# How can a call be made to the Google API from within Django?

Tags: python, django, visual-studio, google-api, google-oauth

I am currently trying to build a web app using Python and Django which will require information from the Google Calendar API. I've successfully managed to create the specific API credentials that I need using the Google Cloud Console, and downloaded the client secret JSON file to use for authentication. I have also been able to successfully access the API using the following code snippet:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow

scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']

flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(r"client secret file location", scopes=scopes)

flow.run_console()
```

When I run it in VSCode, it creates a link in the terminal that I can click to go to the Google site and login. The issue I'm now having though is that the API is treating this as a PC app call, and once it opens in my browser it's asking me to recreate the API key (since the one I created is for Web Apps). A picture of the error can be seen here:

[Authorization Error Message from Google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3chw.png)

Now my question is, is there a way to call the API and have the user login be verified using Django? I am hesitant to remake the API credential as a desktop app because what I'm working on is a Web App afterall. Not sure how to make the call to the API when it is password gated by the individual users' credentials. Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Was using the wrong flow. The flow line should instead have been:

```
flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(r"client secret file location", scopes=scopes)
```